# multiple matplotlib chart using loop

Tags: loops, matplotlib

I need to draw multiple matploblib chart using a for loop.
I have a data from with multiple column of data points and a time series 'year'. I need to create chart for each column.

I have the following code:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Time':['2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019'],
            'A':[1,8,3,10,5,6],
            'B':[2,3,5,2,3,5],
            'C':[7,4,12,11,8,1],
            'D':[3,4,2,2,7,7]})

             x_pos=range(len(df['Time']))
             m,c = np.polyfit(x_pos,df['A'],1)

             plt.scatter(x=x_pos,y='A',data=df)
             plt.plot(x_pos,m*x_pos+c,'--r')
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I used the **matplotlib.gridspec** to achieve this.

Following is the solution:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Time':['2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019'],
        'A':[1,8,3,10,5,6],
        'B':[2,3,5,2,3,5],
        'C':[7,4,12,11,8,1],
        'D':[3,4,2,2,7,7]})

#import gridspec to fit subplots
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

# set grid size 2*2
ggpec = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)
getaxs = []

datacolumns = list(df[['A','B','C','D']])
for i,j in zip(datacolumns,range(1,len(datacolumns)+1)):   
    xpos=range(len(df['Time']))
    getaxs.append(fig.add_subplot(ggpec[j - 1]))
    m,c = np.polyfit(x_pos,df['A'],1)
    getaxs[-1].scatter(x=xpos,y=i,data=df)
    getaxs[-1].plot(x_pos,m*x_pos+c,'--r')

plt.show()
```

The final result will be something like following:

[image]